# Any online step by step toolcalculator for verifing logical equivalence without truth table?

Tags: boolean-algebra, equivalence-relations

Anyone to help me please, I really need to verify logical equivalence without truth table but I can not find any online free tool which I can see step by step the solutions that includes the laws of logical equivalences?

Comment: Ehm ... are you asked to show equivalence using equivalence laws yourself so as to get some practice in the use of those laws, and come to a deeper understanding of them?  Using an automated tool would kind of defeat that purpose ...

Comment: See Carnap (http://dailynous.com/2018/11/07/new-free-open-source-multi-purpose-multi-system-logic-software/)

Comment: @JeanMarie , looks great any where I can download it?

Comment: It's not under the form of a downlable software ; see https://carnap.io/about#usage